# laravel check if two variables in the same row are valid

Tags: php, laravel

How to check if two variables in table but in the same row are exists then do
example
I have customer table have id(autoincreament), customer_id,package id so I want only to check if customer_id and package_id equal to requests then do
I tried this but doesn't work

```
 public function redirectpackage(Request $request)
{
if(Customer::where('customer_id', 'LIKE', $request->customer_id) && 
 (Customer::where('package_id', 'LIKE', $request->package_id))->exists()) {

  return view('index.customer.customerabout'); 
} else
{
 return redirect()->intended(route('home'));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function redirectpackage(Request $request)
{
if(Customer::where('customer_id','=',( Auth::user()->id))->where('package_id','>',0)->first())

{
return view('index.customer.customerabout'); 

}
else
{
return redirect()->intended(route('home'));
}
}

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function redirectpackage(Request $request){

    if(Customer::where('customer_id', 'LIKE', $request->customer_id)->where('package_id', 'LIKE', $request->package_id))->first()) {
       return view('index.customer.customerabout'); 
   } else {
       return redirect()->intended(route('home'));
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to loop through your customers to check against the request for a matching customer ID and package ID.

For example:

```
public function redirectpackage(Request $request)
{

$customers = Customer::all();

foreach ($customers as $customer) {

    if($customer->id', $request->customer_id) and 
 ($customer->packages->id', $request->package_id) {

        return view('index.customer.customerabout'); 
    } else
    {
        return redirect()->intended(route('home'));
    }
}
```

This should get you started.  You'll need to modify to suit your models and relationships.